# Site.com and Google Appliance

Tags: site.com, google-apps

Has anyone ever tried to use Google Appliance with Site.com to index and search for content, as opposed to SFDC records?  I know there's a connector for Google Appliance, but it appears that indexes and searches for records.

Thx,
Hamayoun

Comment: I have used Google Site Search + Site.com w/o issue.  Not Appliance, though.  Can tell you about that if you're interested.

Comment: Peter, does Google Site Search work with authenticated Site.com pages?  And can it be put inside a Site.cm page?  Just to give you more info, we are trying to work out how we can create a SFDC Community, using Site.com pages as the content, and then have a Site Search button within the Community.

Comment: I don't think it is available behind a login.  I've set it up on public Site.com sites.  It is very easy to put on a Site.com page, though. https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/implementingsearchbox

Comment: @PeterKnolle - Google Custom Search is different from Google Search Appliance.  The later is a server that you host yourself in a data center (and is soon to be end of life).  GSA does support indexing of secure content.